# freopen usage to redirect output back to stdout after directing to a file

Tags: c

I'm using freopen for a GUI application using my shared library such that I can redirect debug msgs from stdout to a file

I have been using code based on a snippet from the C++ reference site:

```
/* freopen example: redirecting stdout */
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  freopen ("myfile.txt","w",stdout);
  printf ("This sentence is redirected to a file.");
  fclose (stdout);
  return 0;
}
```

This redirects `stdout` to `myfile.txt` and finally closes `stdout`

Is there a way to redirect to a file then effectively remove the redirection such that `stdout` then prints to screen as usual rather than closing it with `fclose`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not in pure C. If you can assume a specific system (e.g. POSIX) there probably are options.

But frankly, `freopen` is IMO a hack, only needed to be compatible with prewritten code. If you're writing new code you should instead pass the `FILE *` to the relevant functions and use `fprintf` instead of `printf`.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't done it before, but try using dup to make a new file descriptor that is a copy of stdout before freopen, then later use dup2 to copy the properties of that new descriptor back to stdout.

http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup2

This is assuming your system even has dup.  Let me know if it works!

Answer (score 1):

This will return stdout to the display (the default stdout):

```
freopen( "CON", "w", stdout );
```

taken from here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/58667